# Facebook javascript api and iPad, Android

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile

I am try to use FB.login method from facebook javascript SDK .Everything is ok on desktop browsers. But I have a problem with iPad and Android (motorola xoom).

```
unable to post message to recipient has origin www.facebook.com
```

how it can be resolved ?

I am trying to publish a message to the user wall

```
FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
             log("Info: login successfully");
             fbPublish();
           } else {
             log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
           }
         });
```

and when in fbPublish

```
function fbPublish(){
        log("Debug: fbPublish");
        FB.ui({
          method: "stream.publish",
          attachment: {
             name: uatitle.format(myChoice.question, myChoice.answer),
             href: document.location.href,
             media:[{"type":"image","src":"http:.....","href":document.location.href}]
          },
          action_links: [{ text: 'Vote yourself', href: document.location.href }]
         },
         function(response) {
           if (response && response.post_id) {
             log('Post was published.');
           } else {
             log('Post was not published.');
           }
         }
        );
    }
```

so , as I said on desktop everything ok / new post is published successfully . but I have an error on mobile devices

Comment: You need to include way more detail as to what you are trying to do and what code you are using.

Comment: Are you aware that the REST API's *stream.publish* is deprecated?

Comment: no I don't know it. ok , what should I use instead? In any case problem with FB.login, because fbPublish event was not invoked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably move away from stream.publish asap since it is going to be history and start using graph api for posting.

Publishing looks something like this,

```
var params = {};
params['message'] = 'Message';
params['name'] = 'Name';
params['description'] = 'Description';
params['link'] = 'http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/';
params['picture'] = 'my-site';
params['caption'] = 'Caption';

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Published to stream !');
  }
});
```

hope this helps